# Should I implement cookies within my web app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, local-storage

I am making an e commerce store using a react front end connected to an express back end. I wanted a way to persist state so I could keep track of the current user and their cart so I implemented cookies within the app. But after some thought, I've decided to use local storage instead because none of the information that is being stored needs to be sent to the server. Are there any security vulnerabilities that come with not using cookies or am I ok just using local storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But after some thought, I've decided to use local storage instead because none of the information that is being stored needs to be sent to the server.

You made this decision in exactly the right way!

In addition to being easier to work with, Local Storage is a bit more secure and efficient, as you're not sending extra data with each request.

You only need cookies if that's how you're identifying a session.  These days, with so much of sites running client-side, with only API calls being dynamic, there is less of a need for cookies.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, I been doing a lot of research on cookies and I was confused about their use in a client rendered application. Are there any cases where you would want to use cookies when running client-side?

Comment: @noahdubs Aside from working with legacy APIs, not that I can think of.  In my own work, I haven't set a cookie in like 6 or 7 years.

Comment: That's good to hear because I think they're kind of a pain in the ass. I tried to implement them into my web app and kept running into issues with them. Thanks again!

Comment: This answer does not give the full story. There ARE additional security implications when using local storage that aren't present when using http only cookies. See my answer below for more on why XSS is an issue with local storage.

Comment: "Local Storage is a bit more secure". Not really; HTTP Only cookies over HTTPS are much more secure than local storage.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Why do you believe that to be so?

Comment: I can write JavaScript that, when injected, reads a user's local storage entries. I cannot write JavaScript  that can read a user's HTTP Only cookies.

Comment: @HereticMonkey If you can inject script, you can usually reflect whatever you want back through API calls anyway... not to mention what all you can do even if you only had access to the DOM.  I get your point, but I think it's overly pedantic.  Usage of local storage generally does not increase the ways you can be attacked.  You should also weigh the security of sending more data than you need on every requests to servers that don't require it, as often happens with usage of cookies.

Comment: If my point is overly pedantic, I think your statement is overly broad. Usage of any API increases the ways you can be attacked by the surface of the API. I don't disagree with the answer, although I believe the question should not have been answered because it asks for opinions, but making broad statements as a particular technique's security risk is disingenuous and can lead to decisions being made without careful research and consideration.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I don't intend to say "Local Storage is inherently secure", nor do I intend to say "cookies are insecure".    I only intend to say what I said in the answer... that if using local storage can prevent you from having to send some key every request, then it's a *bit* more secure and efficient, and for that one reason.  I hedged a "bit" on that statement for the very concern you have... that someone will say "oh this is magic security yay!".  Of course there are other security considerations, but in this generalized answer for a generalized question, I'd opt for Local Storage.

Comment: @Brad I'm unsure why you continue to consider my answer "irrelevant". My answer specifically addresses the question "Are there any security vulnerabilities that come with not using cookies or am I ok just using local storage?" by fully explaining the security issues that you would be avoiding by using local storage, AND the additional security concerns regarding XSS when using local storage.

Answer (score -2):

Cookies are vulnerable to a specific type of attack known as Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF). I won't go into too much detail as it sounds like you wont be using cookies, but an example of a common attack using CSRF is to embed a form that automatically submits data to one of your api endpoints on a third-party site. If you are using cookie based sessions (and also not using a CSRF token in your api requests), this third party site could now make API requests on behalf of your user if they visit that page.

If you are going to use local storage, you can forget about any CSRF issues that come along with using cookies. With local storage, your primary concern should be regarding XSS (cross site scripting) attacks. If you are using the following anywhere in your React app:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: title}}></div>
```

and the value of `title` is something you loaded in from the server, then you may be at risk of inserting a  tag that could then access the contents of localStorage.

You should always be concerned about potential XSS vulerabilities, as they allow a whole host of attacks. Regarding your question specifically though, if you were to store something sensitive about the user's cart (maybe some personally identifiable information, or a credit card number) in local storage, an XSS vulnerability would give an attacker access to that data.

You can read more about XSS vulerabilities [here](https://dev.to/jam3/how-to-prevent-xss-attacks-when-using-dangerouslysetinnerhtml-in-react-1464).

Edit (response to question by asker in comments):
Say, for example, you are loading a user's username from the database and then you want to display it on the frontend. Before returning the username, you should make sure the value you load from your database only contains the values allowed for a username (in this case, lets say letters and spaces).
You can use a regular expression and the `.match()` function to check if the username only contains the allowed characters:

```js
if(username.match(/[A-Za-z ]+/)) {
  // all good!
} else {
  // there was an invalid character
}
```

Should you sanitize ALL text data that comes from the database? This would probably be inefficient to do for any text field that you select. However, if you will be outputting that data directly to the DOM via dangerouslySetInnerHTML, then it would definitely be a good idea to sanitize it first.

Comment: Is setting the innerHTML within an element the only way I would be vulnerable? Because I don't use any innerHTML code but I do pass a lot of props into elements like so: <div>{props.text}></div>. Also, the only data that I am storing within local storage is the users name, email, id, and cart. Is this considered sensitive information?

Comment: @noahdubs I would not go so far as to say it is the *only* way you are vulnerable. You need to take special care to sanitize any untrusted data that you are outputting to the DOM. This includes values stored in your database (sanitize them when you load them from the db on your server, before sending to the frontend).

Comment: what do you mean by sanitize them?

Comment: what has XSS got to do with cookies? OP is asking to store in cookie or store in localstorage to maintain a logged in token, I presume later a JWT or such goodness. also I'm no expert but does react not need a `<Fragment>` to render non-entity encoded strings?

Comment: This answer is irrelevant to the question asked.  Additionally, there is no security or technical reason why that username couldn't have whatever characters you wanted in it!  If text is text and not HTML, then set the text content of elements rather than the HTML!

Comment: Nope sorry im wrong, there is `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` 

Comment: Not sure why this is being downvoted, the edit is in reponse to a comment where the asker wanted to know about sanitizing user input.  

What has XSS got to do with cookies? Well if you read the question, the question isn't asking about cookies. It's asking about local storage.  

When using local storage, you are not vulnerable to CSRF, but you do become vulnerable to XSS because javascript has access to local storage (but not to cookies that are set to http only).

Comment: @Brad this is incorrect. If we are using a defense-in-depth strategy, we should always sanitize any text data from the database that we want to display in the DOM. This is because you cannot always assume that the data in the database is clean, even if you validate before saving. There could be a bug in your input validation, or someone has found another method of writing data to the database that bypasses your input validation.

Comment: Should you sanitize ALL text data that comes from the database? This would probably be inefficient to do for any text field that you select. However, if you will be outputting that data directly to the DOM via `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, then it would definitely be a good idea to sanitize it.

Comment: Sanitizing isn't the answer.  Just consider for a moment a site like Stack Overflow where it is necessary to have code snippets in user posts.  Those naturally need to appear on the site, but they can't be sanitized... or scripts wouldn't be able to be displayed!  Use proper escaping, or set the text content of the elements.

Comment: Also, the problem has nothing to do with whether you use cookies or not.  XSS can happen either way, if you don't do things correctly.

Comment: @Brad I mention that XSS is something that you should always be conscious of in my answer. As far as escaping goes, I was using a simplified example. Obviously there are specific cases where stripping out every special character won't work.

Comment: @Brad XSS cannot happen if you are using http only cookies, therefore it is an additional security concern when using local storage, therefore it IS relevant to the question.